# Show a progress dialog behind an imageview in frame layout

Tags: android

I want to show an image for first five second of an async task and then show a progress dialog.

Is it possible to display a progress dialog behind that image view for the first five second and then hide that image view and show the progress dialog?

Comment: you can position imageview and progress dialog one over another and make it visible and gone as per your conditions. Regarding 5 seconds condition you can post a delay runnable to execute after 5 second to make it gone and make progress bar visible.

Comment: okay, but the problem is if async task completed before five second, then we close progress dialog on onpostexecute(). Then changing the progress dialog visibility creates error.

Comment: Then i think you require to have a timer task to run after 5 seconds delay. So if async task is finished before 5 seconds in that case you can cancel/purge the timer task

Comment: can you explain your use case? why do you want to show something for 5 sec and then switch

Answer (score 1):

By applying Rajen Raiyarela's suggestion, I made this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act1);

    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swapVisibility();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 5000);

    new Task().execute();
}

class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000); // imitating heavy operation
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        timer.cancel();
        if (pb.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
            swapVisibility();
    }
}

private void swapVisibility() {
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.e("TAG", "Visibility changed");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to sleep the function doInBackground